# Regex optional everything separated by space or comma (city, state)

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to get the street, city, state and zip from a non-well-formed list of addresses, everything but the "street" is optional sequentially. (I can have street, street+city, street+city+state, street+city+state+zip). Separators are either a comma + space, or space only.

So far, I have

```
^(?<STREET>.*?)(?<SEPARATOR1>(?: *-{1,2} *)|(?:, ?))(?<CITY>[a-z-' ]*)?((?<SEPARATOR2>(?: )|(?:, ))(?<STATE>AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY))?((?<SEPARATOR3>(?: )|(?:, ))(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?))?
```

I am having trouble to get a capture after the CITY capture if it's only separated by a space.

Test data:

```
123 Ave Ave - Hoquiam WA 98103
123 Ave Ave - Hoquiam, WA 98103
123 Ave Ave - Hoquiam, WA 98103-1345
123 Ave Ave - Hoquiam
123 Ave Ave - Ocean Shores WA
123 Ave Ave - Ocean Shores, WA
123 Ave Ave - D'ile, WA
123 Ave Ave
```

What am I doing wrong?

https://regex101.com/r/v476Gx/1

Comment: If your city or street has a space in the name like `New York`, what is the logic?

Comment: state is only 2 characters. always

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified `New York` as in city. The issue is with `space only` separators. If it's comma space it's not really an issue.

Comment: Also, what language are you using? So we know which flavour of regex.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/v476Gx/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew almost working! I like the elegance of the separators, but it was not matching line 5 properly. Someone has found a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @jsgoupil Not sure what you mean by "properly" but it is matched. The main difference is that in my pattern grouping is made in such a way that you will only get the next entity of there was a preceding one. You accepted another solution where state and zip do not have to be one after another, and thus, `123 Ave Ave - City, 09812` will be parsed - [maybe better](https://regex101.com/r/v476Gx/5), and in [my case](https://regex101.com/r/v476Gx/4) it will all be parsed as a street.

Comment: @jsgoupil `A[LKSZR]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[ML]|G[AU]|HI|I[DL]|I[NA]|K[SY]|LA|M[EHDAINSOT]|N[EVHJMYCD]|MP|O[HKR]|P[WAR]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[TIA]|W[AVIY]` is shorter, or use `[A-Z]{2}` as Jan's answer suggests. Also, you may run into issues with your first separator. `\ *-{1-2}\ *` will match `-`, which can match, for example `some-thing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some tweaking, following updated regex should work for you:

```
^(?<STREET>.*?)(?:(?<SEPARATOR1>(?: *-{1,2} *)|(?:, ?))(?<CITY>[a-z-' ]*?)?((?<SEPARATOR2>(?: )|(?:, ))(?<STATE>AL|AK|AS|AZ|AR|CA|CO|CT|DE|DC|FM|FL|GA|GU|HI|ID|IL|IN|IA|KS|KY|LA|ME|MH|MD|MA|MI|MN|MS|MO|MT|NE|NV|NH|NJ|NM|NY|NC|ND|MP|OH|OK|OR|PW|PA|PR|RI|SC|SD|TN|TX|UT|VT|VI|VA|WA|WV|WI|WY))?((?<SEPARATOR3>(?: )|(?:, ))(?<ZIP>[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?))?)?$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v476Gx/2)

Answer (score 0):

While you have your answer, this is probably more readable/maintainable:

```
^
(?P<street>[^-\n]+)
(?:-\h*)?
(?P<town>(?:(?!\b[A-Z]{2}\b).)*)
(?P<state>\b[A-Z]{2}\b)?\h*
(?P<zip>[-\d]*)
$
```

See [**a demo o nregex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/r23T0s/2/). It just needs a bit cleaning on the town part.